# what is role of "object array" here?

Tags: javascript

What is the rols of "object array" here:

```js
var  is_array = function(input){
    if(toString.call(input)==="[object array]")//what is role of "object array" here?
       return true   
    return false
}
console.log(is_array('welcome'))
console.log(is_array([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: What might it be, based on the rest of the code? What happens if you run "toString.call" with various data types? See if you can work through this. It's just a string: what it *means* is discoverable in the console in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The code is intended to know whether the argument is an array. Historically there are several ways to do that, although in modern days, the `Array.isArray` function really makes all those tricks obsolete.

First of all, it really should check for **"[object Array]"** (with a capital **"A"**). I suppose that was a typo in your question?

Anyway, here the trick is to use the global function `toString`, which is the `toString` method of the global object (`globalThis.toString`). You might think that you could just have called `input.toString()`, but that function has been overriden by the Array prototype and does not return the same result. It will return the array elements as a comma separated string. The global `toString` function however, will essentially do what [`Object.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) does: provide a generic string in the format "[object *type*]".

By using `call` we can provide the object which should be stringified. And so we get "[object Array]", which is a good indication that we have an array.

Again, nowadays the preferred method is to just call `Array.isArray(input)`.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you give feed-back?